# C# console application won't debug, very strange

Tags: c#, console-application

I created a new console app in an existing solution. Set a break point, and it won't debug.

It opens up and immediately closes down again. Tested another console app in same solution works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's hitting the breakpoint? Sounds like your code is getting to the end without ever going through the logic where your breakpoint is set.

Comment: As a follow up to FreeAsInBeer's point, set a breakpoint at your main function, to make sure you're starting in the right entry point.

Answer (score 8):

Try cleaning the solution and then manually clearing out your bin directory.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes when we have a problem, we avoid the most obvious solutions, but is always helpful to check them.

Have you tried to see if the config of that app is in debug ?

Comment: For some reason, target was set to x86. Fixed and thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For me, unchecking `Optimize code` in the build section of the project's properties solved the issue.

Comment: That was it for me. No idea how that changed, since it worked one moment, next it didnt. VS2022 is super unreliable nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Silly question, but are you sure that the new app is the one that's actually running and not one of the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Visual Studio as an Administrator. I had the same issue and my mind was absolutely boggled for about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when working with a certain sample application, the "Advanced Build Settings, Output, Debugging Information" was set to "Portable". Setting this value to "Full" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following code at the end of your console program.

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: My suggestion (I have suggested/edited modifications): try to improve your English, it is important, and this is good place to do practise. I hope that my modification has mantained the intended meaning, in case of errors, I'm sorry. Also use text formats to separate code/explanation/titles. It makes an answer more understandable. Imho. About the content, yes it stops execution, it is not the better solution ever for debugging, it's a workaround (debug '80 style) :-).